Создание языка программирования на python
Решил попробовать создать пока что простенький язык программирования, который будет иметь задание переменных, арифметика (+ - * /), логические конструкции (== != < >) if/elif/else и цикл for, p() (print()) Всё должно работать ровно как в python.
Уже пробовал с нейросетью, пользовался ply и др. Немного получалось, но было множество ошибок, да и в общем-то я не понимал ничего.
К вопросу. Как написать этот язык программирования? Где можно прочитать про особенности создания, чтобы понять, как пишется код. Также можете, если не трудно, написать этот код и показать как он дорабатывается.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B:%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B,%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B

Наверное для начала стоит почитать книжки -- Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты, Языки программирования - разработка и реализация и т.п.

Или начать с вики

Лиха беда начало:
python.py:
import sys

exec(open(sys.argv[1]).read())

sum.py:
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = a + b
print(c)


$ python python.py sum.py
2
40
42


Но это для разогрева. А на самом деле вам нужно решить следующие задачи:

компиляция: надо прочитать текст программы и преобразовать его во внутреннее представление. Дело в том что ваша программа не может водить пальцем по коду. Надо разобрать все операторы и понять как связаны между собой условия, циклы и вычисления. У нас не BASIC, который допускал интерпретацию прямо из исходного кода.

состояние: вам нужно придумать структуру данных, которая будет хранить все имена и значения переменных, указатель на текущую исполняемую инструкцию и что там ещё понадобится.

интерпретатор: он читает очередную инструкцию на которую указывает указатель, и изменяет состояние: определяет новую переменную или проверяет условие, переносит указатель текущей инструкции. Это делается в цикле, пока программа не завершится.


Самая сложная штука тут – компилятор. Чтобы его было проще написать, надо упростить первую версию вашего языка максимально. Например: for – сложная конструкция, но любой for можно заменить while. Если у вас есть if, то, в приципе, можно обойтись без elif и else. Сложные выражения - удобно, но можно обойтись только конструкциями вида a = 1 + b. И так далее.
Продолжать?

Не для данного случая, но теоретически в усеченном до предела языке можно и if-else заменить на while-s (но функции лучше все же не оставить...)

@avp, ТС не упоминал определение функций. Так что есть возможность обойтись одним словарём значений и указателем инструкций. Потом к этому добавляются более сложные конструкции типа for, if/elif/else, вычисление сложных выражений. Сейчас задача построить простейшее возможное состояние виртуальной машины и запустить его в сотне строк.

Если уж ТС будет делать виртуальную машину, то в ней не обойтись без goto (ну а вообще, ему потребуется понимание организации вычислительного процесса на  уровня ассемблера). Несложно сразу сделать goto с запоминанием адреса возврата (а это и есть основа  вызова функции)

@avp, да goto и ассемблер понадобятся. Иначе надо делать рекурсивный интепретатор (для каждого исполнения тела цикла или ветки условного оператора вызывается новая копия интерпретатора). Кажется goto и ассемблер/байт код выглядят проще как первые шаги. Стек адресов возврата можно ввести позже.

Проще всего будет делать сразу стековую виртуальную машину (можно с двумя стеками, один для операций а второй для операндов). На нее результаты синтаксического разбора исходного кода будут ложиться естественным образом

@avp, это вам проще, вы уже этот путь прошли. Новичку без стека будет легче писать.

Может вы и правы. Каково же будет его удивление, когда потом, переходя к общему случаю, он поймет, насколько проще стала реализация
